# Implement CharSequence in order to use String.join?

Tags: java, string, collections, tostring, charsequence

I have a collection of objects that all override `toString()`.
I want to write them out to console or concatenate to a string, basically creating a `toString()` for the collection.

I can use a for loop to achieve this. `String.join()` seems to be a much nicer way though, because it takes away the explicit loop:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Foo
{
    private double member;

    public Foo()
    {
        member = Math.random();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "I'm foo " + member;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ArrayList<Foo> foos = new ArrayList<>();
        foos.add(new Foo());
        foos.add(new Foo());
        foos.add(new Foo());
        foos.add(new Foo());
        foos.add(new Foo());
        foos.add(new Foo());

        // print collection with loop
        for (Foo foo : foos)
        {
            System.out.println(foo);
        }

        // print collection with String.join
        System.out.println(String.join(System.lineSeparator(), foos));  // fails
    }
}
```

For `System.out.println()` to work, the `toString()` method is called. No interface has to be implemented explicitly. This seems to be easy and is a common practice.

However, to get [`String.join(CharSequence delimiter, Iterable<? extends CharSequence> elements)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#join-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.Iterable-) to work, merely having a `toString()` method is not enough. I need an `Iterable<? extends CharSequence>`, which means `Foo` should implement [`CharSequence`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/CharSequence.html).

Now I quickly implemented that interface by delegating to `toString()`:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

import java.lang.CharSequence;

public class Foo implements CharSequence
{
    private double member;

    public Foo()
    {
        member = Math.random();
    }

    @Override
    public char charAt(int index)
    {
        return toString().charAt(index);
    }

    @Override
    public IntStream chars()
    {
        return toString().chars();
    }

    @Override
    public IntStream codePoints()
    {
        return toString().codePoints();
    }

    @Override
    public int length()
    {
        return toString().length();
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence subSequence(int start, int end)
    {
        return toString().subSequence(start, end);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "I'm foo " + member;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ArrayList<Foo> foos = new ArrayList<>();
        foos.add(new Foo());
        foos.add(new Foo());
        foos.add(new Foo());
        foos.add(new Foo());
        foos.add(new Foo());
        foos.add(new Foo());

        System.out.println(String.join(System.lineSeparator(), foos));  
    }
}
```

But this seems to be quite a bit of code which isn't doing much in this situation except guaranteeing the possibility to convert the object into a `String` which every `Object` has anyway in the form of `toString()`.

The boilerplate code introduced in the solution is bigger than the boilerplate code it removed.

**How can I make a class play nice with `String.join()`?**

Should I go that route and implement the interface or should I run some conversion on the fly?

Comment: You don’t need to implement `default` methods, so `chars()` and `codePoints()` are obsolete. But anyway, implementing `CharSequence` for this purpose still isn’t useful, so stay with the accepted answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on the usage, that route may be inefficient, because each call to a CharSequence method invokes toString anew. For example, if a method tried to iterate over each character, you'd be looking at abysmal performance. Since you are using Java 8, why not use the Streams API?

```
System.out.println(foos.stream()
        .map(Object::toString)
        .collect(Collectors.joining(System.lineSeparator())));
```

Comment: Again, that was a quick implementation, that could be improved in terms of performance. The question is about the boilerplate code necessary to implement the interface.

Comment: Well, yes, you do need to implement all members of an interface. However, if you need to do this for several classes, in Java 8 you could use a purpose-designed interface to act like a C++ mixin with default methods.

Comment: @Javier Martín: well, you only need to implement the `abstract` members, so the question’s example does more work than necessary. Still, your statement about the danger of abysmal performance holds.